# File in use detection not working for pictures/folders

Tags: c#, programming-languages

I am using this code to show an error when `file` is open:

```
try
{
    stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
}
catch (IOException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("file is open!");
}
```

The problem is that code is not working with pictures (jpg, bmp and other) and with folders.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: **Why** would you put code in a `<blink>` tag?

Comment: When you say "not working", do you mean that it doesn't say the file is open even if it is?  How are you opening the file?  Do you have any more specifics?

Comment: No kidding, especially one with a malformed ending tag?

Comment: @Slaks - To make it blink of course ;-)

Comment: The file does not need to remain open to be shown on screen.

Comment: And why do you keep removing our edits?

Comment: Your grammar "fixes" are completely ungrammatical.  Please stop reverting edits.

Comment: What general problem are you trying to solve with your code?

Comment: slaks,,,this code tell u when ever the file is open but in pics its not working

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if I understand what you want to do... I guess you want to find out whether someone is viewing that image currently.

A file is "open" only if some application has an open handle to it. When you use a picture viewer, it is possible (and quite likely), that the viewer opens the file, reads it, and closes it immediately. Hence, the file itself is not use.

This applies to all sorts of files, but many are kept open on purpose (e.g. Office applications will typically keep their files open).

In general, you shouldn't assume that the "file handle is open" and "a human user in some way 'uses' a file" actions are related at all. The file could be open, but no human is interacting (maybe a search deamon is indexing it). On the other hand, a file could be "visible" to the user, but closed on the file system.

Comment: is that mean there is no way to do this..?

Comment: It isn't really well-defined what you are trying to do. You cannot see what a user is doing (if that is what you want) just by looking at the files. Monitoring file operations is very tricky anyhow. Of course you could take screen captures and analyze them somehow, but that is definitely complicated. And I'd be more than worried about privacy. What do you need this for?

Answer (score 0):

this code will not work in your scenario. Then you open the picture system reads the file, uncompress the image and show it to you and closes the file. You can delete it while it is open in Windows.

Comment: is that mean there is no way to do this..?